# Disable MySQL fulltext search stopwords in innodb

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a FullText index on MySQL v5.6 InnoDB table.

and running this query to perform search on the table

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(title,desc) AGAINST ('+hello -for' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

when i run the above query it still gives me the results which includes  word `for` in the title or desc.

I have already made the following changes in my `my.cnf` file to avoid stopwords.

```
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
ft_min_word_len=2
ft_stopword_file = ""
```

Why i am still getting results with word `for` included in it?

Comment: Have you confirmed that  `innodb_ft_enable_stopword` is set to `OFF`?

Comment: no i missed that. i think that is the reason its not working.

Comment: Posted as an answer. Hope that fixed it!

Comment: i will try this and accept the answer if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the server variable [`innodb_ft_enable_stopword`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_enable_stopword) is set to `OFF` if you aren't wanting to use stop words at all.

```
SET @@SESSION.innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 'OFF';
```