# MySQL fulltext index: how to disable stopwords

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, full-text-indexing

Many users are going to search my InnoDB MySQL database for terms like "The Gap", "BT group" or "IG Index" etc. I don't want to annoy them with "zero results".

My code is like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `myTable` WHERE MATCH(tagline) AGAINST('+the +gap' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

One approach would be to remove all stopwords from the queries through PHP, but then I would need to find the full list of stopwords.

I decided to just remove stopwords, following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331135/disable-mysql-fulltext-search-stopwords-in-innodb):

I added these lines to my.cnf file:

```
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
ft_min_word_len=2
ft_stopword_file = ""
```

I emptied my table, ran this SQL in PHPMyAdmin: `SET @@SESSION.innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 'OFF';`
and rebuilt the indexes and added new data.

I am still getting zero results for short terms like "the" and so on.

Comment: Set the global variable, not the session one!

Comment: Yes, SHOW VARIABLES demonstrates its still on. I don't seem to have the privileges to edit this through PHPMyAdmin. Can I find innodb_ft_enable_stopword = "ON" in the my.cnf file?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working now: as @Shadow pointed out, you need to set the variable globally. So:

Added this to my.cnf file:

```
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
ft_min_word_len=2
ft_stopword_file = ""
```

And ensured that this MySQL system variable was set globally:

```
innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 'OFF';
```

Comment: Well, I had a hunch I was missing something subtle.  Glad you got it fixed.